# How to create a ripple effect in a button in an angular way

Tags: angularjs, css

I want to create a button with a ripple effect on clicked.Is it necessary to achieve it through a directive. How do i handle the javascript required to handle the click and propagate the ripple away from the point it was clicked.
I have done it using javascript and css but it is not the angular way.

Comment: I have actually done this ripple thing using pure css and javascript.But i want to do this in a purely angular way. May be through a directive.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import"/>  
  <link href="paper-ripple/paper-ripple.html" rel="import"/>
</head>

<body>
<test-elem></test-elem>
  
<dom-module id="test-elem">
  <template>
    <style>
      div { 
        width: 150px;
        position: relative; 
        padding: 15px;
        border: 1px solid black;
      }
      button { color: green; border: 1px solid green;  }
    </style>

  
    <div>
      <paper-ripple></paper-ripple>
      <button id="btn">Button</button>
    </div>  
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({ is: 'test-elem',
       listeners: {'btn.down': 'onDown'},

       onDown: function(e) {
          e.stopPropagation();
       }
    });
  </script>

  </dom-module>

</body>
```